# Javascript: get package.json data in gulpfile.js

Tags: javascript, gulp

Not a gulp-specific question per-se, but how would one get info from the package.json file within the gulpfile.js; For instance, I want to get the homepage or the name and use it in a task.

Answer (score 121, accepted):

Don't use `require('./package.json')` for a watch process, as using `require` will resolve the module as the results of the first request.

So if you are editing your `package.json` those edits won't work unless you stop your watch process and restart it.

For a *gulp watch* process it would be best to re-read the file and parse it each time that your task is executed, by using [node's `fs` method](https://node.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/fs/)

```js
var fs = require('fs')
var json = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./package.json'))
```

Comment: Agreed that "require" does cache the result (making it unsuitable if you intend to read/modify/read-again). That does not make it a bad solution in all cases though. The OP explicitly mentioned he wanted to read information out of it.

Comment: It's possible to use `require` and the remove the cache with `delete require.cache[require.resolve(FILEPATH)];`

Comment: @KennethB Why not as separate answer? Would drive more then enough upvotes.

Answer (score 142):

This is not gulp specific.

```
var p = require('./package.json')
p.homepage
```

UPDATE:

Be aware that "require" will cache the read results - meaning you cannot require, write to the file, then require again and expect the results to be updated.

Comment: I definitely felt like an idiot for searching for this when I saw your answer. Of course!

Comment: Worked for me :P. And +1 for the comment about caching, I later switched to using 'fs.readFileSync()` as pointed out below.

Comment: @spikeheap I don't know if I've ever laughed out loud before reading a comment on StackOverflow, but I was RIGHT there with you!  Thanks for the cheers.  Haha.

Answer (score 6):

This is a good solution @Mangled Deutz. I myself first did that but it did not work (Back to that in a second), then I tried this solution:

```
# Gulpfile.coffee
requireJSON = (file) ->
    fs = require "fs"
    JSON.parse fs.readFileSync file
```

Now you should see that this is a bit verbose (even though it worked). `require('./package.json')` is the best solution:

## Tip

-remember to add './' in front of the file name. I know its simple, but it is the difference between the require method working and not working.

Comment: Thanks! this helped tremendously.

Comment: thanks for upvotes, finally have comments. :) Glad it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are triggering gulp from NPM, like using "**npm run build**" or something

(This only works for gulp run triggers by NPM)

process.env.npm_package_*Object*

this should be seprated by underscore for deeper objects.

if you want to read some specific config in package.json like you want to read config object you have created in package.json

```
scripts : {
   build: gulp 
},
config : {
   isClient: false.
}
```

then you can use

```
process.env.npm_package_**config_isClient**
```