# Load source files from JSON file in Gulpjs

Tags: json, gulp

I know it's a basic question, but I couldn't find a proper answer.

Is there a way of storing a list of my project's source files in a JSON file and load it on `gulpfile.js`? For example, instead of doing:

```
gulp.src(['a.js', 'b.js'])
```

Do something like:

```
var sources = some_load_file_func('sources.json');

gulp.src(sources.js_files))
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

A gulpfile is just node, and in node you can simply use `require` on JSON files, like so:

```
var sources = require('sources.json');
```

Now sources will be an object (or whatever is in your JSON file).

Comment: Where should this sources.json be? in gulp folder or in project root?

Comment: The `require` function is always relative to the file you are in, or it will look in `node_modules`.  Th answer should have been `require('./sources.json')`, and the file next to wherever you need it, or adjust the path accordingly.

Comment: A word of warning: watch out when using this method with `gulp watch`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29596396/4494577