# Converting `grunt.file.readJSON` to gulp

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, gulp, dot.js

I'm in the process of converting a Grunt file to a Gulp file. My Grunt file contains the following line

```
var config = grunt.file.readJSON('json/config.json');
```

What this line is doing is that it is setting some variables which it then injects into the html it generates, specifically related to languages.

I tried converting the file automatically with [grunt2gulp.js](https://github.com/omouse/grunt2gulp.js) but it always fails with `config` being `undefined`. How would I write `grunt.file.readJSON` using gulp?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to load a JSON file in node/io.js is to use `require` directly:

```
var config = require('json/config.json');
```

This can substitute any `readJSON` calls you have and [also works generally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22645779/javascript-get-package-json-data-in-gulpfile-js). Node/io.js have the ability to synchronously `require` json files out of the box.

Comment: Note that this won't work for files that don't end in `.js` or `.json` (like critical files such as `.jshintrc`, `.jsbeautifyrc` and `.jscsrc`). Node.js is hardcoded to accept-on-extension only, instead of just trying to parse it.

Comment: Yes that's true - but usually file extension is indicative of a type. It's super easy to teach `require` to deal with other extensions.

Comment: usually, but certain automation-critical files that are perfectly valid json do not use that extension (rc files most notably), so for those `grunt.file.readJSON` was a blessing. I was looking for a `gulp` alternative to that, too

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a `.json` file, Benjamin's answer works just fine (just `require()` it in).

If you have any configs that are valid JSON but not stored in files that end in a `.json` extension, you can use the [jsonfile](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonfile) module to load them in, or use the slightly more verbose

```
JSON.parse(require('fs').readFileSync("...your file path here..."))
```

(if you have `fs` already loaded, this tends to be the path of least resistance)

The one big difference between `require` (which pretty much [uses this code](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/ed7fb149a20ee5e7aa9a0574a242a193d7acd761/lib/module.js#L471-L480) to load in json files) and this code is that `require` uses Node's caching mechanism, so multiple `require`s will only ever import the file once, and then return points to the parsed data, effectively making everything share the same data object. Sometimes that's great, sometimes it's absolutely disastrous, so keep that in mind

(If you absolutely need unique data, but you like the convenience of `require`, you can always do a quick `var data = require("..."); copied = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));`)

Comment: It's super easy to add these hooks to `require` for other file extensions. There are advantages to using `require` (it's cached, and native) IMO.

Comment: Interesting, do you have a link to docs? I've been using Node.js for a few years but have never seen anything but Node itself do that. As for native, [the code for loading .json](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/ed7fb149a20ee5e7aa9a0574a242a193d7acd761/lib/module.js#L471-L480) is pretty much this code, the only real difference is the caching that you get with `require`, so that's a good point: will edit to mention that!

Comment: `Module._extensions['. jscsrc']= Module._extensions['j.son']` , this is how CofeeScript and Babel and everything else that hooks on node does it :)