# How do I parse a .json file in Gulp to pass along to Firebase?

Tags: json, file, firebase, gulp

Alright so I have YAML files, that are being transformed into JSON files. That part is done. But I need to read the JSON files into their appropriate json objects to send to a Firebase Database.
Current gulpfile:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var yaml = require('gulp-yaml');
var replace = require('gulp-replace');
var firebase = require('firebase');
var paths = {
    yaml: ['~/devel/Git/core-rules/feats/*.yml',
        '~/devel/Git/core-rules/banes/*.yml',
        '~/devel/Git/core-rules/boons/*.yml']
};

require('firebase/auth');
require('firebase/database');


// compile rules from yaml to json and output to
gulp.task('yaml', function(){
  gulp.src(paths.yaml)
    .pipe(yaml({
        space: 2
    }))
    // replaces newlines from YAML "foo : |" linebreaks
    .pipe(replace('\\n', '<br />'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./app'))
});
```

It has no dependancy problems, but only reads 1 file (there should be 3)
I need to get the JSON that was written (once there's a JSON file for each YAML file) into a JSON object. Once that's done, it'll be set/pushed to the firebase database.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to: @hapticdata and @Jon Surrell

```
var fs = require('fs');

var json = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./data.json'));
```

[Duplicate of Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22645779/javascript-get-package-json-data-in-gulpfile-js)